# Регулярные выражения, вытащить числа из строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Задача:

- В строке найти число от 1 до 100 000 000 (отделенное табуляцией)

Я не знаю я регулярку (пока).

Comment: Учите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/info

Comment: `[\d\t]+`, однако не ограничено границами. Если нужно именно до `100 000 000`, то стоит решить другими средствами, регуляркой можно, но не нужно (монструозно выйдет).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\t\d{1,8}\b`

`\t` - табуляция;
`\d{1,8}` - 1-8 цифр без пробелов (100 000 000 не входит);
`\b` - граница слова.

Вместо `\d{1,8}` можно написать `(\d{1,8}|100000000)` - тогда 100 000 000 входит

Comment: тогда 100000000 взодит